# What does "(int) value & 0x1, (int) value & 0x2, (int) value & 0x4, (int) value & 0x8" mean?"

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

> [image: code]

The "value" ranges from 0 to 15 (its possible values). When will those 4 "if" conditions be met? If my (int)value = 2 does this mean 0010?

```
            if  ((int)value & 0x1) 
            {
                //statement here
            }
            if  ((int)value & 0x2) 
            {
                //statement here
            }
            if  ((int)value & 0x4) 
            {
                //statement here
            }
            if  ((int)value & 0x8) 
            {
                //statement here
            }
```

Comment: Those are [bitmasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) checking for individual bits of `value` (read `if(value & 0x4)` as "Is the 3rd bit of `value` set (=1)). As you seemingly have problems understanding the code, I assume it is not yours. This (and the fact that you are not asking for review) makes this question off-topic for [CR.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For better understanding, similar code that has been ported to C# will use the `Enum.HasFlag` method to test for bits. See: [Enum.HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 12):

Each number can be expressed as `value = b0*2^0 + b1*2^1 + b2*2^2 + b3*2^3 + ...` with each b being either `0` or `1` (these are the bits of the representation). [This is the binary representation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number)

The binary AND (`&`) takes each of those `b` pair wise and performing AND on them. This has the following outputs:

```
0 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

Using powers of 2 (which have only a single bit on) we can isolate and test the individual bits:

- `value & 1` is true when `value` is odd {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15}.
- `value & 2` is true when `value/2` is odd {2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14 ,15}.
- `value & 4` is true when `value/4` is odd {4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14 ,15}.
- `value & 8` is true when `value/8` is odd {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ,15}.

The 0x prefex on the numbers means it should be interpreted as a [hexadecimal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). It is a bit superfluous when you only go up to 0x8 but tells maintainers it is probably used as a bitmask.

Comment: The wording may suggest that it can be extended to all numbers, which is not true: `8/6` is odd, while `8&6` yields false.

Comment: @Sjoerd that's why I said "powers of 2"

Answer (score 5):

These if-statements check if a specific bit of `value` is set.

The hexadecimal value `0x4`, for example, has the 3rd bit from the right set to `1` and all other bits set to `0`. When you use the binary-and operator (`&`) with two operants, the result will have all bits set to `0` except for those bits which are 1 in both operants.

So when you do the calculation `value & 0x4`, you either get binary `00000000` or binary `00000100`, depending on whether or not the 3rd bit of `value` is `1` or `0`. The first evaluates to `false`, and the second to `true`, so the if-block is only executed for values where the 3rd bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

There are two interesting things to note here.

First, this is a common pattern for checking each of the low-order 4 bits of an integral value. The if condition is met if the corresponding bit is set. For the value 2 the bit pattern is indeed 0010.

The other more interesting question is why the `(int)` cast? Apart from the bad style of using C-casts in C++, no integer or character values require this cast. A bool makes no sense, a double/float would be converted to an integer temporary and it would be unusual to use literal values to test an enum. It might make sense with a pointer, but that would be a very specialised use. Conclusion: the cast makes no sense.